# Optimizing AWS IoT Costs with Basic Ingest: Utilizing Ingest Topics and Publishing Messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I've been exploring AWS IoT Basic Ingest as a means to reduce AWS IoT message broker costs. Despite referencing the official AWS documentation (link: [AWS IoT Basic Ingest Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-basic-ingest.html)) and attempting to configure it as per the instructions provided, I've encountered some roadblocks. The configured setup doesn't seem to be functioning as expected.

I would greatly appreciate your assistance in shedding light on the best practices and effective steps for utilizing AWS IoT Basic Ingest to optimize costs. Are there any specific nuances or troubleshooting steps that I should be aware of to resolve this issue?

Additionally, I am keen to understand how to publish messages to the ingest topics within AWS IoT Basic Ingest. What are the recommended approaches, necessary SDKs, or tools needed to accomplish this task efficiently? Detailed guidance, code examples, or a step-by-step walkthrough would be invaluable at this point. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No response in 12 days. So, here a little hint that our customers learn and test AWS IoT applications with https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/aws/ . Here's a 2 minute video with Basic Ingest https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmJnWOY1I2Q